# NullError: method not found: 'appendChild' on null

Tags: angular, dart

I get no errors in chrome console when run `pub serve` and open http://localhost:8080

I use `angular: '^4.0.0'` and `sdk: '>=1.24.2'`

But when I run pub build and open build/web/index.html, nothing work and I get errors in chrome console:

```
main.dart.js:10583 EXCEPTION: NullError: method not found: 'appendChild' on null
STACKTRACE: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at EN.$0 (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:9422:3)
    at EU.dart.EU.$0 (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:9393:14)
    at N7.dart.x3.func (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:3058:35)
    at bK.dart.bK.E8 (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:10339:7)
    at Object.eval (eval at qf (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:1851:15), <anonymous>:2:41)
    at Qw.aY (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:4346:12)
    at bK.aY (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:10386:30)
    at pY.aY (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:9314:3)
    at pY.z4 (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:9317:28)
    at file:///home/vitaliy/Apps/web_lko/build/web/main.dart.js:9289:12
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: NullError: method not found: 'appendChild' on null

(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:10583
main.dart.js:10583 EXCEPTION: FormatException
STACKTRACE: 
FormatException
    at Object.d (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:1720:3)
    at Object.mz (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:1582:37)
    at Object.bL (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:1587:21)
    at file:///build/web/main.dart.js:33670:5
    at W6.a (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:2908:72)
    at W6.dart.W6.$2 (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:3146:24)
    at Vm.dart.Vm.$1 (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:3142:31)
    at N7.dart.x5.func (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:3065:35)
    at bK.dart.bK.Ea (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:10346:7)
    at Object.eval (eval at qf (file:///build/web/main.dart.js:1851:15), <anonymous>:2:43)
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: FormatException

(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:10583
main.dart.js:1251 Uncaught Error: NullError: method not found: 'appendChild' on null
    at EN.$0 (main.dart.js:9422)
    at EU.dart.EU.$0 (main.dart.js:9393)
    at N7.dart.x3.func (main.dart.js:3058)
    at bK.dart.bK.E8 (main.dart.js:10339)
    at Object.eval (eval at qf (main.dart.js:1851), <anonymous>:2:41)
    at Qw.aY (main.dart.js:4346)
    at bK.aY (main.dart.js:10386)
    at pY.aY (main.dart.js:9314)
    at pY.z4 (main.dart.js:9317)
    at main.dart.js:9289
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: How do you open `build/web/index.html`? Is this from WebStorm/IntelliJ or are you using something else? These IDEs automatically start a server that serves to the browser. Opening Angular applications directly from disk without any HTTP server isn't supported because of Chrome security constraints.

Comment: I try with idea, and I get errors too: https://gist.github.com/Rasarts/d6ed9ec03c91f79a53977ec147636ba9

Comment: What happens if you build it with `pub build --mode="debug"`? Do you get the same error?

Comment: With --mode="debug" I get not erros, only warnings: https://gist.github.com/Rasarts/d6ed9ec03c91f79a53977ec147636ba9#file-pub_build_mode_debug

Comment: Ok, then it seems to be a tree-shaking issue. I don't know how to fix, but I guess creating a bug report in http://dartbug.com/new would make sense.

Comment: I try run: `rm -rf .pub && pub upgrade && pub build --mode="debug"`
and all work without console errors in browser. But warrings still there on build. It's works only with `--mode="debug"` but I whant add `web: compiler:debug: dartdevc` to pubspec.yaml. With  `pub build --mode="release"`I get errors in browser. I can't use dart2js with release mode?

Comment: What warnings do you get when you build with `--mode="debug"`? Do you get the errors only with `dartdevc` or also without it? `dartdevc` is only relevant for `pub serve` not for `pub build`. "I can't use dart2js with release mode?". Yes, normally you can, but it might be a bug.

Comment: I made issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30718 Whith `web:
  compiler:
    debug: dartdevc
    release: dartdevc in pubspec.yaml` I get no erros and warnings and all works fine.

Comment: `release: dartdevc` doesn't make sense. `dartdevc` is only for development. For release/deployment you need `pub build` (`--mode="release"` is default)

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, could we see a bit more of your code? If not here, than at least in the github issue. The first error looks like you're trying to `append` to an element that you have gotten through something like `querySelector(...)', and that CSS selector does not match anything on the page. DDC runs okay (apart from the warnings)?

Comment: Hi. DDC runs okay without warnings or errors. Here is client part of our application: https://github.com/Rasarts/lko_client_only.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct:

```
<script defer src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
<script defer src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

Incorrect:

```
<script src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```